# Project Euler - Problem 3 c++

Tags: c++

Ok, it's done...it took me a month but life is hard (and I'm pretty stupid myself) and I would like to know your opinions about it, do you think I can make it better?, more efficient?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

unsigned long long int a = 600851475143;
unsigned long long int i = 1;

while (a!=1) {
    i=i+1;
    if (a%i==0) {
        while (a%i==0){
            a=a/i;
        }
    }
}

cout << "Its greates prime factor is: "<< i << endl;
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: *"I have no idea how to do it..."*. So is this working code?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear and I'm sorry to bother but I have no clue on how to progress from here.

Comment: I can't view post history, but this site is structured around a Q&A format. This means that it is frowned upon to edit your post (or at least the code portion of it) to not invalidate existing and WIP answers. Just an FYI. Also, welcome to Code Review!

Comment: Oh!, I didn't know...- I'll take it down then, just so I find out how to properly post the question, thank you!!!

Comment: You can save half of work by not testing divisibility by 2 and its multiples: `i+=2;`

Answer (score 2):

#### Do not use `using namespace std`

In general you should avoid `using namespace std` because it is often considered as a bad practice since it could lead to name collisions (for more details see [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) post on StackOverflow).

#### You don't have to `return 0`

You don't have to explicitly `return 0;` at the end of `main`. According to the standard:

> **3.6.1 Main function**
>
> ¶5 A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main
>   function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control
>   reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the
>   effect is that of executing
>
> `return 0;`

#### Avoid globally using of `std::endl`

[`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is not the same as just `\n`. The only difference is that `std::endl` flushes the output buffer, and `\n` doesn't.

There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14395960/8086115) on SO about this topic.

#### Use short syntax

Instead

```
i = i + 1;
```

you could write just

```
i++;
```

As well as for `a = a / i;` (the short form is `a /= i;`).

#### Avoid unnecessary condition

This `if` statement

```
if (a % i == 0)
```

is unnecessary because exact the same condition check in the `while` loop.

Comment: I'd avoid getting into minor style details such as whether to use braces for single-statement `if`/`for`/`while`, this is indeed just a matter of taste or the coding style mandated by the project you're working on.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, yeah, you are right, But I just decided to mention that this style is also allowed. May be the author will like it.

Comment: It may be legal c++ but it is very bad practice to omit braces, especially with nested statements. Don't recommend it, and don't suggest that it's just an aesthetic choice.

Comment: @Josiah, no, it is not a bad practice, it is just a matter of taste. For example Linux kernel coding style allows omit unnecessarily braces. But, for example idSoftware's DOOM 3 coding style doesn't. And I do not recommend it, just mentioned that this style has the right to exist.

Comment: @Josiah, I have deleted this part of answer. It is my first answer and may be you are right that it is not a good idea to mention style things.